# Why isn't j1939.h include in the Ubuntu 18.04 Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, can-bus, socketcan

I am trying to use CAN J1939 standard on an embedded Linux system running Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 5.4.0-52-generic.

[This elinux page](https://elinux.org/J1939) indicates that j1939.h "got in the mainline kernel since v5.4". And [kernel.org's documentation for j1939](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/networking/j1939.html) implies that it is in the main kernel.

Lastly, I do have can-utils installed.

When I compile a cpp file with `#include <linux/can/j1939.h>`, I get a `no such file or directory` error.

I've gone through `linux/can` directory to confirm and `j1939.h` is not there. Is there any reason why my v5.4 kernel wouldn't have `j1939.h`? How can I best use `j1939.h` in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need development packages for these headers. You can search for which package you need on the Ubuntu Packages site. I.e. in this case  [packages containing j1939.h](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=j1939.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any). You're probably looking for `linux-libc-dev` or `linux-headers-5.4.0-26`.

Comment: Ahh good information. Is there some obvious way to know if some header requires an additional package?

Comment: Normally, if you need headers, you're going to need dev packages. It makes little sense for the "general" linux desktop to contain CAN-related headers, so they're not installed by default. Your best bet is to simply search on the page I linked to see which packages are necessary. If they're already installed, Ubuntu will tell you.

Comment: @Cameron If this answers you're questions please upvote/accept it.

Comment: It actually appears as though [there isn't a package available for Bionic, 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=j1939.h)  with `j1939.h`. In that case, is there another best practice to use that header?

Comment: Ah, that's pretty annoying. What you can try is to download the .deb files for both the headers and the package itself from the Ubuntu Package website and install those manually. Not ideal, but often that does work.

Comment: Gotcha. Would you recommend placing it in the expected directory `/usr/include/linux/can/` or would it be better to include it in my project includes?

Comment: When installing the .deb files they'll be placed in the correct location automatically. But even if installing manually, I'd recommend not to place them inside your project, because that would be pretty "non-standard" for system headers.